# Инсталляция и подключение ConfigObj Python

Tags: python, config

Здравствуйте, Всем!

Возникла необходимость подучить питон. В нем я еще только разбираюсь. Необходимо подключить сторонний модуль - в данном случае `ConfigObj`. Скачал архив, распаковал - все как надо. Пытаюсь инсталлировать для того, чтобы питон увидел данную библиотечку.

в CMD:

```
python "C:\path-to-folder\setup.py" install
```

получаю:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
file configobj.py (for module configobj) not found
file validate.py (for module validate) not found
file configobj.py (for module configobj) not found
file validate.py (for module validate) not found
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install
```

Что не так?:) Информации, на удивление не так уж и много в интернете. Особенно, что касается установки модуля под виндой. (У меня 8-ка)

Answer (score 1):

UAC включен? Попробуй от администратора запустить. Похожее у процесса нет прав на запись в папку.

Comment: Не уверен, что нашел лучшее решение. Но я просто скопировал нужные *.py файлы в директорию lib и все заработало. Странно, что не инсталлировалось. Mysql-python библиотека через exe-шник нормально встала.